# Datetime picker not outputting value in the field

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, field

```
<?php 
// In the functions.php
add_filter( 'wcv_product_title', 'product_title_date' ); 
function product_title_date( $args ){ 
    $args[ 'class' ] = 'wcv-datetimepicker'; 
    return $args; 
}
?>
```

On the front end I’m able to select date and time but it doesn’t show up the date in the field.

This is what outputs when I select a date and time, I attached a screenshot. So it's F j, Y.
[image]